# Firefox: How to execute a .bat file from a link?

Tags: batch-file, firefox, cmd

Here I have a little intranet page which has some "file://" links on it. These links point to some Windows batch files. However, if I click on these links, I see only the content of this batch file. I would rather get the Firefox dialog where I can choose between open, save and cancel.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

```
Content-type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.txt"
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html

it should ask you if you want to run the bat.
If the page page is only for internal usage it will be better to try with HTA application - it will have no restricitions of the browser and you will be able to call the bat with  a vbscript.